# Partner branch locations

Tags: odoo

I have a partner A with different branches (A, branch1) , (A, branch2) in OpenERP 6.1

Do I need to create a separate partner for all branches and then point their parent partner field accordingly or am I missing something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is, do you deal directly with each of the branches (sales orders, invoices, etc.) ?

- If you do , you should open a Partner for each branch, so you can relate
  each document with the corresponding Partner's Branch.
- If not, the
  you are dealing with a partner having with several branches, and it
  will suffice to have a Partner with several Contact addresses.

Comment: thanks, i got the point. Though presently i am only trying to record the leads & opportunities received from different branches but the invoices are also from the same branch.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ask the branches if they have separate bank accounts. If so then you should create a separate partner account otherwise make one partner account and find a way to put different branch accounts into that.